# Unexpected 'List Index Out of Range' Issue in Desktop App with No Prior Modifications

Tags: python, json

I have a Python desktop app that has been seamlessly reading 2 JSON files that have NEVER changed for the past 4 years. Suddenly, I'm encountering a 'List index out of range' error with no apparent reason. Despite my attempts to debug, I am struggling to identify the specific issue. It appears that the code is unable to access the 'Location' value of a JSON key, leading to a failure when performing calculations. My app uses google maps api to calculate distance, and it uses google calendar api to insert meetings in google calendar. Here is the traceback error:

Here is the traceback error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYYhn.png)

Tried to debug bug no luck at all, was expecting to find why the code can't read the json file correctly, if that is the problem

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, please also include the actual code. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for a non-empty list of length N the valid index range is -N -> N-1

Therefore, the issue you have is that either:

```
directions["routes"]
```

...or...

```
directions["routes"][0]["legs"]
```

...are empty lists